# Magento 1.9 coupon code being applied but total not updating

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

I have a simple 20% discount coupon code setup in a Magento store. In the cart when the coupon is applied the discount amount is shown but the grand total does not update e.g.

Subtotal £23.95

Discount - £4.79

Grand Total £23.95

I have checked the 'Mage_Tax' module is enabled, re-indexed everything but it still isn't working. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?